Python pandas groupby get FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead
The code:
df_chart = df_esn.groupby([date], as_index=False, sort=False)\
         [ffperN1,'DFF_ESN'].mean()

get the error message:
FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.
Could you show me how to fix it?

Please add a sample dataframe generating the above error.
